# C++ finding type of subclass with a pointer to superclass

Tags: c++, pointers, raytracing

In my C++ code, I have a vector of pointers to a Light object. P_Light is a subclass of Light, and has a field position. For each pointer pointing to a Light that is actually a P_Light, I need to do something with the position field. I did some searching and it seems like I can implement a virtual method, but I don't need the method in Light since other types of Light don't have a position. I also thought about casting but I'm not sure how to make that work.

```
std::vector<Vector> light_dirs;
for(int i=0; i<lights.size; i++){
    Light *l = lights[i];   
    //cast here?
}
```

EDIT::
Saw in a different post that maybe using qobject_cast would be a good idea. Does this look better?

```
std::vector<Vector> light_dirs;
for(int i=0; i<lights.size; i++){
    Light *l = lights[i];   
    P_Light* pl = qobject_cast<P_Light*>(l);
    if(pl != nullptr) //dostuff;
}
```

Comment: You code doesn't match. `light_dirs` vs `lights`, `Vector` vs `Light`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. This is happening in a method, with parameter:
Ray ray, std::vector< Light * > &lights

Comment: Unrelated, but unless the pointers' lifetime is handled elsewhere you may be setting yourself up for some nice memory leaks. Consider using smart pointers.

Comment: @user657267 I'm too scared to valgrind, writing a raytracer so I have millions of rays and tons of surfaces...

Comment: @jstn Learn to use it. Very handy tool. Also keeps me from quoting Yoda at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
P_Light* p_light = dynamic_cast<P_Light*>(l);
```

Check RTTI and dynamic cast on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

Comment: Thanks! so does my edit look ok? I used qobject_cast instead. I just wasn't sure if that's the best way to do it.

Comment: It looks like you can use the function 'qobject_cast' on QT programming framework. 'dynamic_cast' is a function within C++ standard function, so any decent C++ compiler should compile this without any problem.

Comment: @jstn You shouldn't be using `qobject_cast` unless you have objects which inherit from `QObject`, of course all of this would require the use of Qt.

Comment: @JamesAdkison just noticed, I got qobject_cast from a 10 second google. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

As Seo points out, a dynamic cast is probably the most straight forward way to quickly accomodate the use case you describe without refactoring the class structure.

As an alternative, you might consider an implementation using the Visitor pattern, which provides compile time safety and verification.

```
class P_Light;
class NP_Light;

/* abstract class providing dispatching based on 
 * whether Light objects interact with the position field */
class Light_Visiter{
  virtual ~Light_Visiter(){}
  virtual void visit(NP_light&) = 0;
  virtual void visit(P_Light&) = 0;
};

class Light{
  virtual ~Light(){}
  virtual void visit(Light_Visitor&) = 0;
  // other methods
};

class P_Light : public Light{
  void visit(Light_Visitor& lv){lv.visit(*self);}
  // other methods
};

/* Light objects which do not interact with the position
 * field inherit from NP_Light */ 
class NP_Light : public Light{
  void visit(Light_Visitor& lv){lv.visit(*self);}
  // other methods
};
```

This provides you same advantage as a dynamic cast -- your classes remain independent of the algorithms that operate upon them -- but the logic for dispatching is centralized rather than dispersed throughout your source.

For more information on the visitor pattern, see this nice [article](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html).